# Custom ConstraintLayout attributes

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-constraintlayout

I've noticed a lot through the usage of ConstraintLayout, that there's a lot of boilerplate that could be easily reduces with more attributes.

For example, rather than

`app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"`

why not have a
`app:layout_constraintHorizonal_toInnerOf="parent"`

or for the vertical axis `app:layout_constraintVertical_toInnerOf="parent"`

(where Inner or Outer could differentiate between `end to start/end of` or `top to top/bottom of` etc.)?

Likewise, why not have an attribute to constrain all sides?
`app:layout_constraintAll_to="parent"`

I also commonly use parent or 0dp on both sides plus on the top or bottom (but not both, so only defining three sides), to constrain an element centered to the top or bottom of the screen.

I think all of these would be extremely useful, **since you almost always use multiple constraints at once, and often to the same element**, so it would make the XML easier to read and files shorter.

So my questions are:

- Is there a documented reason why google hasn't already provided this like with padding and margin?
- And what would be the best way to manually implement this?

Possible solutions might be:

- Extension functions
- A custom child class of ConstraintLayout (though I don't really know how ConstraintLayout actually works yet, but it looks quite complicated, with no functions seemingly related to certain attributes, just a lookup table to enums and stuff)
- styles.xml (but this gives a warning about not being constrained to the element, and afaik doesn't support multiple inheritance even among styles, making it impractical)
- BindingAdapters (although this may produce the same warnings as the styles.xml approach)

This is more a curiosity than something I actually need.

Comment: "why haven't google already provided this" -- questions of the form "why did Developer X make Decision Y?" are not good questions for Stack Overflow. Usually, only Developer X can answer the question, and it is unlikely that Developer X will see the question. Usually, anyone else can only offer opinions.

Comment: You would have to either make a custom `ConstraintLayout` implementation or as you've said use binding adapters (if using data binding). Extension functions have no relevance here.

Comment: Just out of interest, what errors are you referring to with constraints being in your style resources? This should work just fine.

Comment: Making xml smaller and easier to read is not really a goal, if anything providing multiple attributes that manipulate the same property would bring confusion. Believe me I did have my cases of losing time setting up `padding` just because I was inheriting `paddingLeft` from style I wasn't aware of.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ah, true. I was wondering if there was a reason was documented somewhere; such as it isn't possible because of x, rather than just their opinion.

Comment: @HenryTwist Android Studio likes to yell at me for not constraining an element on some axis if it's done through styles. Although, it does work, so maybe it's best to suppress the warning? Having said that, as far as I can see, you can only inherit one style, and each style can only have one parent, which makes that approach problematic.

Comment: @Pawel As you've already mentioned, all, vertical, and horizontal options already exist for padding and margin, so it strikes me as odd that this isn't also provided for constraint.
Also, why shouldn't making shorter and easier to read XML files be a goal? And does `padding` not override `paddingLeft` like in CSS?

Comment: Ah of course, I didn't consider the constraint warnings. However I think that things like that shouldn't really be in your styles anyway, so I don't think I'd go ahead and suppress anything. In reply to your other comment, there defintiely wouldn't be a technical reason to not provide horizontal and vertical 'shortcut attributes', likely just a design decision.

Comment: Also my suggestion of a custom `ConstraintLayout` would actually be quite simple to implement. However it wouldn't solve the warnings. Looks like you're stuck with the standard library for now.

Comment: But, consider filing a feature request, if there isn't already one for this already. Your idea is good, but to an extent `ConstraintLayout` is *too* central for that kind of tweak to be made ad-hoc by developers. Bear in mind that the Jetpack team is under some of the same constraints (pun lightly intended) as you: even if they add these attributes, it is up to a separate team to change Studio and the build tools regarding the warnings.